# my LG monitor attached to Dell laptop not showing display

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a [Dell XPS L502x WIndows 7 (64 bit) laptop](http://www.dell.com/in/p/xps-l502x/pd) and a [LG Flatron W1943C LCD Monitor](http://www.lge.com/br/monitores/lg-W1943C-monitores-lcd-widescreen). I want to add LG monitor as a seconday monitor to my laptop using HDMI port. I'm using HDMI to VGA cable.

My Display control panel is detecting the monitor but nothing is coming there.

[image]

Screenshot of setting when no external monitor cable is attached. I don't know what it's showing 3-4 screens.

[image]

Please help to attach this external display to my laptop

Comment: have you tried the various Multiple monitor modes (ie, duplicate, extended desktop, projector only)? Do all of them result in no display in monitor? Can you please put a better screenshot of the other monitor when it's connected to the laptop?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with either cable or a driver. At least, Windows should **not** report monitors ##3, 4, and 5. Please try replacing HDMI cable, connecting the monitor via the mini DisplayPort, and updating video drivers.

Comment: @Sathya - Will post it tonight